single phase submersible pump auxiliary binding start/run sequential or parallel?
I have a single phase submersible pump which is auxiliary binding that need start and run capacitor.
Does start and run capacitor giving phase shift to be started
a) Sequential (like trigger start capacitor and when it reaches desired speed (75-80%) then turn off start capacitor  and turn on run capacitor) ?
b) Parallel (Like trigger start and run capacitor together and turn off start capacitor when it reaches desired speed) ?
Which one is the right approach and why. I searched internet I could find both type of wiring so it confusing which one is the right approach. Motor starter with contactor usually triggers them sequentially but without contactor they trigger them parallelly and cut of start capacitor when green start button is released.

That information would usually be on the pump's datasheet or faceplate. Can you provide a link or a photo?

Actually its a submersible pump and already gone underground. I am editing title to make it clear that it is submersible pump. I do not have the datasheet of it currently. It was installed couple of years ago and I need to change its starter. when I studies starters I got confused because starters with both approaches are available in the market
